# What does $g \to \lambda$ mean in the L-System for the dragon curve?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, formal-grammars

I am playing with [L-System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system) using the wonderful tool [`jflap`](https://www.jflap.org/). Below is the L-System for [the dragon curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system#Example_6:_Dragon_curve) in the "JFLAP book: JFLAP – An Interactive Formal Languages and Automata Package
" (you can find it in the left column of its homepage).

What does the third rewriting rule "$g \to \lambda$" mean? I did not find any references.

[image: dragon-rules]

[image: dragon]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"$\lambda$" is commonly used to represent the empty string, although "$\epsilon$" could be the more common one.

This was introduced earlier in that book, section "3.1 Grammar Editing" of chapter "Regular Grammars".

> On the last row you will enter the production $A \rightarrow \lambda$, a
> $\lambda$-production. To do this, enter $A$ into the left cell, but leave the right cell blank. **The right field is really empty, but will display with a $\lambda$** to signify that it is a $\lambda$-production.

In the case of $\text{L}$-system, a $\lambda$-production rewriting rule means the symbol on the left will be gone in the next iteration.